# Chrome dev tool setting breakpoints on an html attribute value change

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Using chrome dev tool, how can I set breakpoints on html attributes, so that when the html attribute value changes, the debugger stops at that line where the breakpoints are set ?

Thanks in advance.
Dani

Comment: I have already tried the following with no success;


1-Click the Elements tab.

2- Go the element that you want to set the breakpoint on.

3-Right-click the element.

4-Hover over Break on then select Subtree modifications, Attribute modifications, or 
   Node removal.

Comment: The only explanation then is that the parent/ancestor element with its entire tree was replaced/recreated so try setting the breakpoint [much] higher in the hierarchy.